# How to expand User(AbstractBaseUser) with OnetoOneField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want relate my Profile model with User model from class AbstractUserModel with OnetoOneFields. Is it possible? Or any solution with this problem. Here my models.py

```
from django.db import models
#from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser
)


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    active      = models.BooleanField(default=True) 
    staff       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin       = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' 
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active



class Profile(models.Model):
    #HERE
    user                = models.OneToOneField(AbstractBaseUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nama_lengkap        = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    tgl_lahir           = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    alamat              = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    foto_profil         = models.ImageField(upload_to='foto_profil',blank=True)
    jabatan             = models.ForeignKey(Jabatan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.user, self.nama_lengkap)
```

when I migrate this, just show some errors message like this:

SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
users.Profile.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'AbstractBaseUser', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
users.Profile.user: (fields.E307) The field users.Profile.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'auth.abstractbaseuser', but app 'auth' doesn't provide model 'abstractbaseuser'.

thanks in advance

Comment: have you added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'` in your settings.py ??

Comment: No, is that needed?

Comment: Yes, since you are using a custom user model

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace this

```
user                = models.OneToOneField(AbstractBaseUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

with

```
user                = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: still no choices "User" when I try added Profile row via localhost:8000/admin/users/profile/add/

Comment: have you added any user in your database?

Comment: in phpmyadmin i have auth_user and users_user.

Comment: have you created any user in you user table or not ?

Answer (score 0):

However I recommend you doing it different way:
Instead of creating second User model, extend existing one:

````
#models.py
class ProfileUser(AbstractUser):
    extra_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20) # modifing existing field
```
```
#settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app_name.ProfileUser"
````